# Why is the dtype shown (even if it's the native one) when using floor division with NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, division, numpy-dtype

Normally the `dtype` is hidden when it's equivalent to the native type:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(5)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> np.arange(5).dtype
dtype('int32')

>>> np.arange(5) + 3
array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

But somehow that doesn't apply to floor division or modulo:

```
>>> np.arange(5) // 3
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
>>> np.arange(5) % 3
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int32)
```

Why is there a difference?

Python 3.5.4, NumPy 1.13.1, Windows 64bit

Comment: Because the 1st example dtype is actually `None` which is displayed as the default `int32`

Comment: Can't reproduce (Python 3.6.0, NumPy 1.13.1, SuSE Linux, 64-bit Python and 64-bit NumPy).

Comment: Can't reproduce either (Python 3.5.2, Numpy 1.11.1, Lubuntum, 64-bit)

Comment: @JBernardo: What makes you say the dtype is None? (Note that `dtype(None)` is treated as `dtype('float64')`, not int32.)

Comment: `np.arange(5, dtype=None)` vs `np.arange(5, dtype=np.int32)` @user2357112 Not on every context

Comment: Possibly only on 32-bit systems, since we get `dtype('int64')` on 64-bit systems? Or else possibly windows specific?

Comment: I agree with @o11c, on windows only python 32  is installed maybe?

Comment: @JBernardo: If `arange` gets `None` as the `dtype` argument, it infers the dtype from the other arguments; it doesn't actually use None as the dtype, and None isn't displayed as int32.

Comment: It's 64bit windows with 64bit Python (anaconda). It could very well be windows specific (`int32` is the default integer dtype on windows, no matter if 32bit or 64bit System/Python).

Comment: The default for integer types on any numpy is `int32` and `float64` for float types. This means that if dtype is None it will select one of each based on the actual type you input, like `arange(5)` and `arange(5.0)` @user2357112 
So the actual dtype is really `None`, but once you ask for it it will generate the correct one

Comment: @JBernardo I'm not sure that's what happens. But why is the dtype also omitted from the representation if I use `np.arange(5, dtype=np.int32)` which definitely has a not-None dtype?

Comment: @MSeifert I think you are right about `np.int_`. When you pass `dtype=None` it is using it. I just checked again

Comment: Having examined the [logic](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.1/numpy/core/numeric.py#L1885) NumPy uses to print the `repr` of arrays, I don't see any way that logic could have produced the behavior you describe. Something may have overridden that logic, or you may have screwed up your test somehow.

Comment: @user2357112 There's one possibility: `np.intc` (that's also a 32bit integer on Windows) and `np.intc in _typelessdata` gives `False`. But I don't get how floor division or modulo would map `np.int_` to `np.intc`.

Comment: @MSeifert: Do you see True or False for `np.intc == np.int32`?

Comment: The `np.intc == np.int32` gives `False`. But `repr(np.intc)` shows `numpy.int32`.

Comment: I think NumPy may have (accidentally?) created two distinct 32-bit integer types, possibly corresponding to C `int` and `long`.

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour using the code in the question on Python 3.5.2, Numpy 1.13.1, 64 bit Windows 10. I'm using CPython (not Anaconda or anything)

Comment: Interestingly, I can't reproduce this in Anaconda 2.7, 64-bit, on Windows 7, so it might be specific to P3 too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually have multiple distinct 32-bit integer dtypes here. This is probably a bug.

NumPy has (accidentally?) created multiple distinct signed 32-bit integer types, probably corresponding to C `int` and `long`. Both of them display as `numpy.int32`, but they're actually different objects. At C level, I believe the type objects are `PyIntArrType_Type` and `PyLongArrType_Type`, generated [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/68a58e03a1661b8d95877771f6e7fa87ddf7c183/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src#L3543).

dtype objects have a `type` attribute corresponding to the type object of scalars of that dtype. It is this `type` attribute that [NumPy inspects](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.1/numpy/core/numeric.py#L1885) when deciding whether to print `dtype` information in an array's `repr`:

```
_typelessdata = [int_, float_, complex_]
if issubclass(intc, int):
    _typelessdata.append(intc)


if issubclass(longlong, int):
    _typelessdata.append(longlong)

...

def array_repr(arr, max_line_width=None, precision=None, suppress_small=None):
    ...
    skipdtype = (arr.dtype.type in _typelessdata) and arr.size > 0

    if skipdtype:
        return "%s(%s)" % (class_name, lst)
    else:
        ...
        return "%s(%s,%sdtype=%s)" % (class_name, lst, lf, typename)
```

On `numpy.arange(5)` and `numpy.arange(5) + 3`, `.dtype.type` is `numpy.int_`; on `numpy.arange(5) // 3` or `numpy.arange(5) % 3`, `.dtype.type` is the other 32-bit signed integer type.

As for why `+` and `//` have different output dtypes, they use different type resolution routines. [Here's](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/umath/ufunc_type_resolution.c#L1104) the one for `//`, and [here's](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/umath/ufunc_type_resolution.c#L587) the one for `+`. `//`'s type resolution looks for a ufunc inner loop that takes types the inputs can be safely cast to, while `+`'s type resolution applies NumPy type promotion to the arguments and picks the loop matching the resulting type.

Comment: In my test case, the `.type` attribute is the same.

Comment: @hpaulj: Really? Did you test with `is`?

Comment: I see you've tested with `is` now, and found that they're different.

Answer (score 2):

It comes down to a difference in the `dtype`, as can be seen from the `view`:

```
In [186]: x = np.arange(10)
In [187]: y = x // 3
In [188]: x
Out[188]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [189]: y
Out[189]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
In [190]: x.view(y.dtype)
Out[190]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)
In [191]: y.view(x.dtype)
Out[191]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3])
```

Even though the `dtype` `descr` are the same, there's some attribute that's different.  But which?

```
In [192]: x.dtype.descr
Out[192]: [('', '<i4')]
In [193]: y.dtype.descr
Out[193]: [('', '<i4')]

In [204]: x.dtype.type
Out[204]: numpy.int32
In [205]: y.dtype.type
Out[205]: numpy.int32
In [207]: dtx.type is dty.type
Out[207]: False

In [243]: np.core.numeric._typelessdata
Out[243]: [numpy.int32, numpy.float64, numpy.complex128]
In [245]: x.dtype.type in np.core.numeric._typelessdata
Out[245]: True
In [246]: y.dtype.type in np.core.numeric._typelessdata
Out[246]: False
```

So `y`s `dtype.type` by all appearances is the same as `x`s, but it's a different object, with a different `id`:

```
In [261]: id(np.int32)
Out[261]: 3045777728
In [262]: id(x.dtype.type)
Out[262]: 3045777728
In [263]: id(y.dtype.type)
Out[263]: 3045777952
In [282]: id(np.intc)
Out[282]: 3045777952
```

Add this extra `type` to the list, and `y` no longer shows the dtype:

```
In [267]: np.core.numeric._typelessdata.append(y.dtype.type)
In [269]: y
Out[269]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3])
```

So `y.dtype.type` is `np.intc` (and `np.intp`), while `x.dtype.type` is `np.int32` (and `np.int_`).

So to make an array that displays the dtype, use `np.intc`.

```
In [23]: np.arange(10,dtype=np.int_)
Out[23]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [24]: np.arange(10,dtype=np.intc)
Out[24]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)
```

And to turn this off, append `np.intc` to `np.core.numeric._typelessdata`.

Comment: I'm not sure the `.type` comparison is that useful because that also gives different types for `np.int_` and `np.int32`. Or am I wrong?