# NumPy array output differs when using exponentiation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Quick question about the output using NumPy arrays in a Jupyter notebook.

I've defined a simple array `arr = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int32)`, and was doing a few operations just to get used to syntax and whatever, and noticed the following:

```
In: arr * arr
Out: array([1, 4 ,9])

In: arr * 5
Out: array([5, 10, 15])

In: arr ** 2
Out: array([1, 4, 9], dtype=int32)
```

For exponentiation, the output includes the `dtype`. It seems pretty innocuous, as it didn't change the datatype to `int16` (why would it) or anything like that, but there's an obvious difference there and I'm curious to know if there's a reason behind it, like something happening under the hood that dictates the output behaviour.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46285518/why-is-the-dtype-shown-even-if-its-the-native-one-when-using-floor-division-w

Comment: @user2357112 Huh that's interesting, I didn't see the question when searching. Turns out exponentiation results in an `intc` `dtype` while the original array is `int32`. Thanks for pointing that question out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL:DR summary of the solution in the commented link provided by @user2357112 above:

```
In: arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])

In: arr.dtype.type
Out: numpy.int32

In: (arr ** 2).dtype.type
Out: numpy.intc

In: (arr.dtype.type) == (arr ** 2).dtype.type
Out: False
```

Hence, the `dtype` is printed. This is cause of some C funkiness.